# Sorting Characters followed by alphanumeric in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to sort the characters first followed by alphanumeric like below.

```
[Austria , Germany , 123aed , 234eds]
```

This is what i have tried

```
obj.sort((a,b) => {
  if (
      (isNaN(a.text) && isNaN(b.text)) || (!isNaN(a.text) && !isNaN(b.text))
  ) {
    return a > b ? -1 : 1;
  }
  else {
    return isNaN(a) ? -1 : 1;
  }
})
```

But it is sorting in this way

```
[123aed , 234eds , Austia , Germany]
```

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 0):

try the function `localCompare`

```
["Austria" , "Germany" , "123aed" , "234eds"].sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b));
```

Comment: It is coming in the reverse order i.e [ 123aed , 234eds , Austria , Germany]

Comment: try reversing the compare to `b.localeCompare(a)`